# Remove iFrame scrollbar and place it on DIV

Tags: html, css, iframe, scrollbar

I'm trying to get rid of the iFrame scrollbar and give this task to the container div. The thing is that I'm using margins so I don't like to have the scrollbar in the middle of the page. I would like to move it o the very right of the screen.
Is there any way to achieve that?

my code is:

```
div#content {
    background: white;
    left: 3%;
    right: 3%;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 80px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

On the iFrame I have added

```
scrollbar = no
```

but then I cannot see the whole content.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the size of the iframe. Then the container div needs to have `overflow-y: scroll`

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/cj771ry7/1/